# C# System.Timers.Timer Class elapsed event and timer general precautions

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, threadpool

Two questions.

One: in a winforms application is it a good or bad idea to have a system.timers.timer be enabled and disabled inside of it's elapsed event so that the main UI thread can have access to variables and methods that were created on that main UI thread? So for example with code:

```
myElapsedTimerEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
   timer.enabled = false; 
   /***Call some functions and manipulate some variables***/
   timer.enabled = true;
}
```

Two: In anyone's experience, what are some precautions and dangers to be warned about the system.timers.timer in winform and c#? Are there any examples that you can provide about things that could happen with the hardware and/or software if a timer is not used properly?

Any suggestions for using system.timers.timer would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why not use the Windows Forms Timer?

Comment: Can there be multiple instances of a windows.forms.timer? Reason being is that the app that is being made needs to do at least two things at once. Could a windows forms timer accomplish a task like that?

Comment: Disabling and re-enabling the timer will cause it to be out of sync... e.g. if your timer is set for 1000 ms but it takes 10-20 ms for your code to execute, timer events will fire every 1010-1020 ms, which may make a difference to you. If you are worried about two elapsed events accessing the same variables at the same time, I suggest using a `lock`.

Comment: I appreciate the quick replies. I will look into both the forms timer and the lock. If there is any other suggestions, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: @Enigmativity Is it possible to have more than one instance of a windows.forms.timer? For example can I can windows.forms.timer timerOne AND windows.forms.timer timerTwo?

Comment: @someuser193 - You can have as many as you want. Why not test it out?

Comment: @Enigmativity and everyone else who took the time to look at this post. Thank you for your suggestions and replies. I have switched to using System.windows.forms.timers and I am very pleased with the results. I have declared multiple windows.forms.timers instead of system.timers.timers and the code is much safer now and works. Everyone's help is much appreciated! Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: @JohnWu Thanks for your reply and time to look at this post! I have looked into the lock and I think it will be useful in  the app. Your time is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to set the `Enabled` property of a timer from inside the event handler, provided that the event handler is executed in the UI thread. Otherwise it is not safe, because the `System.Timers.Timer` class [is not thread-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer#thread-safety). The make the handler execute in the UI thread you must set the [`SynchronizingObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject) property of the timer to the current `Form`. For example:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer = new Timers.Timer(5000);
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
}
```

If I am not mistaken, this assignment happens automatically when you use the designer to add a `Timer` in a `Form`.

My suggestion though is to use the [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer), because it comes without thread-safety considerations. You are not restricted to only one timer. You can have as many of them as you want. Just keep in mind that their handlers are running in the UI thread, so you should avoid putting lengthy code in there, otherwise the responsiveness of the UI may suffer.

Comment: Theodor Zoulias, Thank you for your time and detailed explanation. I have taken the suggestion of using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer. I am using multiple forms timers to handle things in the code and I feel much better about the results and the safety of the program. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!!